# С чего начать практиковать нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Хочу начать изучать нейронные сети, параллельно читаю книгу о них, и поймал себя на мысли, что чтение и практика две разные вещи.

Можете подсказать источник для изучения, где можно практиковаться или какой-нибудь задачник?

Answer (score 2):

Практикуйтесь на каггле https://www.kaggle.com/. Там постоянно появляются новые задачи = соревнования, которые вместе с другими людьми можете решать, у кого лучше метрика на тестовых данных, тот и выиграл. К тому же там можно делится своим кодом, что тоже поможет в обучении.

Answer (score 1):

Книгу читать нужно,практиковаться на keras(проще с быкендом Theano).Протестировать логические операции И,Или,Хоr,научится сохранять весы и модель,восстанавливать ее,Андрей Сазонов на youtube кул по kerasu,желательно свой перцептрон написать хоть однослойный с numpy.

Comment: Библиотека Theano же закончилась, а Keras теперь взаимно интегрирован в Tensorflow. А так то Keras плюсую, конечно.